# Ulianna Stratagem 6-pc + Madstone interaction

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I'm wearing the full [Uliana's Stratagem](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ulianas-burden) set. Its 6-piece bonus is:

> Your Seven-Sided Strike detonates your Exploding Palm.

I'm also wearing [Madstone](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/madstone), which means:

> Your Seven-Sided Strike applies Exploding Palm.

I'm hoping that, as per [this link](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/18700824414), Madstone would proc first, applying and then detonating EP. It certainly seems to *apply* it, but enemies that don't die from SSS appear to still have EP applied to them.

Is EP really detonating as the US-6 bonus dictates it should? It's hard to tell because, in all other cases, it only detonates in death (so there's nothing left for it to be applied to).

(I know that Madstone is probably overkill for most applications; I'm just experimenting with the build :)

Comment: When I played u6 last season I think I remembered it as it alternates between applying and detonating EP with each SSS hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your madstone applies the EPs after the hit

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: If you hit no enemy twice, you will see no explosion, thats why.